# how to refer to a base class's derived class?

Tags: c++, stl, static-cast

```
class Element { };
class Container {
    vector<Element*> elements;
};
```

The above is the original code. I was told not to change the above code. Now I have

```
class IndexElement: public Element {
    int b_index;
};

class Container* ctr;
```

Now I have `ctr->elements`. But `Element` has no member `b_index`. Any simple method to redirect the attribution of `elements` from `Element` to `IndexElement`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't.  A base class has no idea it is being used as a base class.

Comment: _"Any simple method to redirect the attribution of a2b from b to bson?"_ Unless you use definite interfaces  no. Also an instance of `ason` never can be casted to `bson` correctly.

Comment: I think it's how to access the members inside the objects stored inside `a2b`. Not casting `ason` to `bson`.

Comment: The original code won't compile, so you might just throw it away (or show the *real* code).

Comment: Are you looking for [virtual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) functions??

Comment: I think, the code is super convoluted for no reasons. I will edit to be less convoluted, but express the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have one option: you *know* that you have a `IndexElement` and not a `Element` in the vector, and then you can use `static_cast<IndexElement*>(elements[i]);`. Be aware that if you don't have only `IndexElement`, then this will utterly break.

If you can modify b, then you have another option, by making b virtual. If you don't know, you may have `Element`s and `IndexElement`s, and in that case use `dynamic_cast<IndexElement*>(elements[i]);` and test it the result is `nullptr` or not. In this instance, b *must* be virtual (hence virtual destructor).

(I assume we are in `Container`, so direct access its members)

Full trial (that will break because no allocated `elements`) with the modified Elements:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Element{
public:
    virtual ~Element() {}
};

class Container{
    public:
vector<Elements*>elements;
};

class IndexElement: public Element{
int index;
};

int main()
{
    Container aa;
    static_cast<IndexElement*>(aa.elements[0]);
    dynamic_cast<IndexElement*>(aa.elements[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, even without virtual and RTTI (dynamic cast) you still have the option to track and check the `IndexElement` instances created, for example:

```
std::unordered_set<Element *> idxElemSet;

class IndexElement: public Element {
    int b_index;
public:
    IndexElement(int index) : b_index(index)
    { idxElemSet.insert(this); }

    IndexElement(const IndexElement& other) : b_index(other.b_index)
    { idxElemSet.insert(this); }

    // might also need the move constructor in case of c++11

    ~IndexElement()
    { idxElemSet.erase(this); }

};

int main()
{
    Container c;
    ...
    Element* e = c.elements[0];

    if (idxElemSet.find(e) != idxElemSet.end()) {
        IndexElement* ie = static_cast<IndexElement*>(e);
        // do something with ie->b_index
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So you can basically keep the set of addresses of all the instances created and when checking the particular instance, just check if the current object address is in the set.

The `idxElemSet` can be also static inside `IndexElement` and the class itself might just provide static conversion function which does the check and conversion internally, etc.